No data shown in Applicaition Insights
I am trying to make a method to log my traces in some programs. But I struggle to get a connection to my Azure Application Insights and see the data I want to log.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Create a service collection and configure Application Insights
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Category", LogLevel.Information));
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService((ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions options) => options.ConnectionString = "cnxn string");

        // Build ServiceProvider.
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Obtain logger instance from DI.
        ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

        logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
    }

I tried to follow Microsofts own documentation on how to log to Application Insights:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#net-corenet-framework-console-application
The manual part, worked fine, I and I could manualy log and flush to Azure, but that is not what I want.
In the end, it would be nice that I could simply send the logger as a parrameter for future methods, so that I can easily log to Azure.

Please note it might take a few minutes for the logs to be available.

Thank you, but I can confirm that there is nothing in the logs.


In the end, it would be nice that I could simply send the logger as a parrameter for future methods, so that I can easily log to Azure.

I introduced an interface named ILoggerService with three logging methods: LogInformation, LogWarning, and LogError. This interface defines the contract for logging services.
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WorkerSDKOnConsole
{
    public interface ILoggerService
    {
        void LogInformation(string message);
        void LogWarning(string message);
        void LogError(string message);
    }

    public class AzureLoggerService : ILoggerService
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public AzureLoggerService(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }

        public void LogInformation(string message)
        {
            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Information);
        }

        public void LogWarning(string message)
        {
            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Warning);
        }

        public void LogError(string message)
        {
            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Error);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the telemetry client.
            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient()
            {
                InstrumentationKey = "Ins-key"
            };

            // Create the logger service.
            var loggerService = new AzureLoggerService(telemetryClient);

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            while (true) // This app runs indefinitely. Replace with actual application termination logic.
            {
                loggerService.LogInformation($"Worker running at: {DateTimeOffset.Now}");

                loggerService.LogWarning("A sample warning message. By default, logs with severity Warning or higher are captured by Application Insights");

                loggerService.LogInformation("Calling bing.com");
                var res = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://bing.com");
                loggerService.LogInformation($"Calling bing completed with status: {res.StatusCode}");

                telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Bing call event completed");

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            // No need to flush telemetry client here.
        }
    }
}


Modified the Program class to create an instance of AzureLoggerService instead of directly using the TelemetryClient.
Replaced the direct calls to TelemetryClient.TrackTrace with calls to the corresponding methods of the loggerService instance (e.g., loggerService.LogInformation).
Removed the explicit flushing of the telemetry client from the Main method. Since we're using the Application Insights SDK, it handles flushing automatically.

By this I can enable easy logging to Azure Application Insights throughout the application by injecting the ILoggerService dependency where needed.


Updated:

Utilize mocking frameworks like Moq or NSubstitute to create mock implementations of the ILoggerService interface. These frameworks simplify the process of creating mock objects and defining their behavior during tests.

[TestClass]
public class ProgramTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Main_LogsInformation()
    {
        // Arrange
        var loggerServiceMock = new Mock<ILoggerService>();
        var program = new Program(loggerServiceMock.Object);

        // Act
        await program.Main(new string[] { });

        // Assert
        loggerServiceMock.Verify(x => x.LogInformation(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
    }
}


Interresting to see this, never thought about doing it this way using ILoggerService as an interface. But it does not look very test freindly when doing UnitTests?

Yes, using an interface like ILoggerService can pose challenges for unit testing, especially if you're not using a mocking framework. However, it's not inherently untestable please re-check my updated answer.
